# How to retrieve the list of documents from iCloud without using UIDocumentPickerViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, uidocumentpickervc, icloud-documents

I open picker with documents from iCloud with the following code:

```
let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: 
["public.content"], in: .import)
picker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
picker.delegate = self
self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

My question is how can I get teh list of documents without showing this controller? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: dayitv89, sadly no